# How to deny other users/roles from creating EC2 instances with an IAM role

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I have an S3 bucket with confidential data.

I added a bucket policy to allow only a limited set of roles within the account. This stops other user from accessing the s3 bucket from console.

One of the allowed roles, say "foo-role" is created for EC2 instances to read the S3 bucket.

Now, even the denied roles can create a VM, assign the "foo-role" to this VM, ssh into this VM and look at the bucket content.

Is there a way that I can prevent other users from assigning the "foo-role" to their EC2 instances.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this policy to your IAM Users. This policy will prevent a user from associating or replacing a role to an EC2 instance.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "DENY",
      "Action": [
         "ec2:AssociateIamInstanceProfile",
         "ec2:ReplaceIamInstanceProfileAssociation",
         "iam:PassRole"
      ],
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks John. These users had full EC2 access. Explicit denial on the "foo-role" stops them from using that role.